# Razor Page Scaffolding: No code generators found with the name 'razorpage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to add scaffolding for a new page in my Razor Pages project. However, I keep getting the following output in the ASP.NET Core Scaffolder:

```
Checking if needed NuGet packages are already installed…
Building project…
Running /Users/lukeengland/Projects/AssetManager2/AssetManager2/obj/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --configuration "Debug" --project "/Users/lukeengland/Projects/AssetManager2/AssetManager2/AssetManager2.csproj" razorpage --model User --dataContext NewUserContext  --referenceScriptLibraries  --useDefaultLayout --no-build -outDir "/Users/lukeengland/Projects/AssetManager2/AssetManager2/Pages/Users2" --namespaceName AssetManager2.Pages.Users2 --useSqlite 
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
No code generators found with the name 'razorpage'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String codeGeneratorName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:03.28
No code generators found with the name 'razorpage'
```

This happens when trying to create scaffolding using any model in my project. I was able create scaffolding for some pages a few weeks ago so not sure what has changed since then. Any suggestions greatly appreciated

P.S: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 on a Mac

Comment: Can you tell us the version of your Asp.net core application? And which version of `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` are you using? Perhaps the issue is related to the `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`, try to re-install them.

Comment: I am using version 3.1.4 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design.
Under the Frameworks menu, it says Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is version 3.1.8

Comment: I have just tried re-installing the CodeGeneration and CodeGenerationDesign packages but problem still persists

Comment: Whether you are using the VisualStudio's Scaffolding dialog to add the razor page, like [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac)? According to this tutorial, I have created a new sample to test, it seems that everything works well. If still not working, try to execute the command `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator -h`, it the command could not execute, try to use the following command to install the aspnet-codegenerator in global: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly same error on VS Mac and version of 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design'. Instead of using VS wizard, using dotnet CLI seems able to work around and create all the scaffold files, but will need to see if it really works..Still learning:)

please try:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --configuration "Debug" --project "/Users/lukeengland/Projects/AssetManager2/AssetManager2/AssetManager2.csproj" razorpage --model User --dataContext NewUserContext  --referenceScriptLibraries  --useDefaultLayout --no-build -outDir "/Users/lukeengland/Projects/AssetManager2/AssetManager2/Pages/Users2" --namespaceName AssetManager2.Pages.Users2 --useSqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Ubuntu using CLI scaffold tool. The workaround for me was downgrading the SDK (and ) to `3.1.301` version as said in this [github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1393#issuecomment-689630572):

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-3.1=3.1.301-1
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me when trying to create a razor page EF scaffolding using visual studio for Mac with latest .NET 5.

```
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
No code generators found with the name 'razorpage'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGeneratorsLocator.GetCodeGenerator(String codeGeneratorName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:03.76

No code generators found with the name 'razorpage'
```

I was able to create the scaffolding by running the dotnet CLI

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --configuration "Debug" --project "/Users/Max/Repos/VSProjects/WebApplication/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj" razorpage --model Movie --dataContext WebApplication.Data.WebApplicationContext  --referenceScriptLibraries  --useDefaultLayout --no-build -outDir "/Users/Max/Repos/VSProjects/WebApplication/WebApplication/Models" --namespaceName WebApplication.Models --useSqlite
```